# Microsoft Office desktop/app version

Tags: discussion

Despite the confusion with the payment model between Microsoft Office (one time payment) and Microsoft Office 365 (subscription). There is the issue between the different installation versions. You can install it either as an "app" or as as a "desktop application". The current tags don't differentiate but the two version are technically different.

As far as I understand, the app version only works with an office 365 subscription (I'm not completely sure though). However with the 365 subscription you also have the possibility to install a desktop application and it will "overwrite" the app (just tested that).

What would be good tags to differentiate between the "desktop version" and the "app version"?

Comment: The are functionally the same program aren't they? I thought it was just that one used a "streaming download" system and the other was a monolithic download. The programs are identical except in how they are installed, or are they not?

Comment: @Mokubai that what I though at first, but they are not. The shared(!) top level function like formulas features in excel etc. might be overall similar (but details are still differences), and they don't share all functions. Further in depth the differences get bigger due to fundamental differences on how apps are implemented into windows (in regards to "regular desktop applications").

Comment: For now I assume what you say about differences is true. It looks like the differences are not obvious. If we differentiate on the tag level, some users will probably choose whatever tag *seems right*, without even reading the excerpt(s) or tag info(s). Then the community will have to keep reviewing the tags, keep sorting out. And since the differences are not obvious, the community will possibly fail, at least temporarily. Instead of one tag that covers the two cases we can end up with two tags, each covering the two cases in practice. This scenario should be taken into consideration.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good point, I'll give it a thought, thanks!